# First Sign-in after Signup Show Config Page Once Effectively

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to show a popup or a template page if user has signed in for the first time after sign up basically allowing them configure some stuff on that page before going to dashboard home, It's only needed for convenience and here is what I got (telescope code)

```
Router.onBeforeAction(hasCompletedChannels);

  hasCompletedChannels: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userCompletedChannels(user)){
      this.render('connectChannels');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  }
```

Which I don't really like because this will always run every time, I want it to run just once, And don't even execute the check function. Is it possible to detect first sign in? (After signup)

Comment: @gunr2171 a more effective way will be: Run it once after condition met which = first time signin after signup if possible? not everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just tie it to the specific route. Right now you're tying it to the Router object (every render forces that check as you point out). So if you define your login function to send someone to a specific route after sign-in, you could just verify on that route.

The function `Accounts.onLogin` gives you a way to do stuff after the login.

Something like

```
Router.route('profile', {
  path: '/profile',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    // Check some stoof
    // If first time logged in 
    //   render first time template
    // else
    //   this.next() will render the profile page
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      // some subs
    ];
  },
  data: function() { 
  // some data 
  }
});
```

I'm assuming that its going to get routed to a page called profile (seems to make sense). You could check for first time logged in by some attribute you use in the user object and the fields you want filled out and force a render of a different template, or a subtemplate. Check out the Iron Router guide for more ideas on ways to configure it.

Best of luck